# Cant transfer file from Bluehost to SiteGround via SSH

Tags: ssh, hosting, putty

I have a website that I'm trying to migrate from Bluehost to SiteGround.

I compressed the website into a zip file, i created the SSH access within SiteGround and i'm successfully connected to it, when i try to transfer remotely the zip file located on bluehost i get an error saying:
"**Could not resolve hostname ssh...**"

Usually for transferring files i use the same methods with other hosts, only this time it doesn't not work between Bluehost -> SiteGround

This is the command line i'm using:

**cp -r https://oldhost.com/myfile.zip /
scp -r https://oldhost.com/myfile.zip /**

Does anybody have an idea why this is not working? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't run `cp` and `scp` together like that.

Assuming you are currently logged into the NEW server when you run the command, I would probably run something like this:

`scp -r user@oldhost.com:/path/to/myfile.zip /path/to/new-server/location`.

Note that you can change the `oldhost.com` to an IP address if the DNS cannot resolve.

Comment: Thank you for your help. What shall i put instead of "user", should i leave it as it is? Or put something instead?

Comment: Replace `user` with your own username. Use your own credentials to access the remote server.

Comment: I'm on SiteGround SSH, when i run the command: "scp -r cpanelusernameoldhost@oldhost.com:/path/to/myfile.zip /path/to/new-server/location" i get the following error: "Permission denied (publickey)" why is that?

Comment: Have you added your new server's public ssh key to your user's `authorized_hosts` file on the old server?

Comment: OMG, i have not. So that's why it was not working. Thank you so much David !